# Testing value of nested property in chai-as-promised and mocha

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to test a function that returns a promise using the *chai-as-promised* library. The result in my promise is an object with nested properties. Is it possible to test a deeply nested property's value.

E.g.

```
function myFunc() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const data = {
      thing: {
        foo: 'bar',
        baz: 'lah'
      }
    }
    resolve(data)
  })
}
```

How can I test that the `foo` property equals "bar" without checking the entire object? I've tried something like this:

```
expect(myFunc()).to.eventually.have.property('thing.foo', 'bar')
```

But no luck!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using deep property lookup should work. Just add the `deep` keyword before `property`.

```
expect(myFunc()).to.eventually.have.deep.property('thing.foo', 'bar')
```

If you prefer the verbose way, you should also be able to do stuff like:

```
expect(myFunc())
   .to.eventually.have.property('thing')
   .that.has.property('foo')
   .that.is.equal.to('bar');
```

Comment: What if you're using "assert" instead?

Comment: I think this is wrong -- shouldn't it be `.to.eventually.have.nested.property`? This works to see if anywhere in the object, including below the root, has a key `thing.foo` and a value `bar`, but `.nested.property` checks if `returnValue.thing.foo === 'bar'`.

Comment: I haven't used chai for quite a while. I can't say for sure, have you tested?

Comment: @QuentinRoy That's the issue I just ran into; as far as I can tell, this changed at some point in the past. Several times `.deep` is referred to as correct, but they're all fairly old.